# cut/paste duplicate values in multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

having trouble creating a macro that can do the following.

Values in column A and C
Digits in column B and D

the Macro needs to compare the data of column A and B against column C and D and cut / move the duplicate data to Sheet2. it needs to be in the exact same format as sheet 1.  value, digits, value, digits.

at the end i should be left with all entries in columns A:D of entries that did not match and in sheet 2 all the entries that did match

i tried playing with the code i received from a previous question but not having any luck.  it does not seem to want to search for both columns.

```
example:
Sheet 1 before start
Column A   Column B   Column C   Column D
20         10         10         20
10         7          17         10
10         20         8          7
10         7          10         7

then afterwards:
Sheet 1:
Column A   Column B   Column C   Column D
20         10        17         10
10         7         8          7

Sheet 2:
Column A   Column B   Column C   Column D
10         7          10         20
10         20         10         7
```

my attempt does not check both columns but only one column since i have no idea how to check for both, then a second one that copies the info from the second column to sheet 2. the if statement on when to copy does not work properly and there is no loop yet.  my knowledge on vba is very limited

```
Sub Matchin()

Dim wsMain As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
Dim lRowColA As Long, lRowColB As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim Acell As Range, ColARng As Range, ColBRng As Range

'~~> Set input Sheet and output sheet
Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Balancing")
Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Remove")

'~~> Start Row in output sheet
j = 1

With wsMain
    '~~> Get last row in Col A & B
    lRowColA = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lRowColB = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    '~~> Set your actual data range in Col A and B
    Set ColARng = .Range("A1:A" & lRowColA)
    Set ColBRng = .Range("C1:C" & lRowColB)

    '~~> Loop through Col A
    For i = 1 To lRowColA
        If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then
            '~~> Check if there are duplicates of Col A value in Col B
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ColBRng, _
            .Range("A" & i).Value) > 0 Then

                '~~> If found write to output sheet
                wsOutput.Cells(j, 1).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value
                wsOutput.Cells(j, 3).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value

                '~~> Find the duplicate value in Col B
                Set Acell = ColBRng.Find(What:=.Range("A" & i).Value, _
                LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                '~~> Clear the duplicate value in Col B
                Acell.ClearContents
                '~~> Clear the duplicate value in Col A
                .Range("A" & i).ClearContents

                '~~> Set i = 1 to restart loop and increment
                '~~> the next row for output sheet
                i = 1: j = j + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i

End With
End Sub

Sub bit()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim cola As Integer, colb As Integer, rng As Range, n#, b#

cola = Range("A1:A8000").Count
colb = Range("B1:B8000").Count

If cola <> colb Then

Range("A:A").Select

Selection.Find(What:="", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Copy
Sheets("Remove").Select
Range("B:B").Select
Selection.Find(What:="", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial

Sheets("Balancing").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
ActiveCell.Resize(1, 2).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp


End If

End Sub
```

any help would be appreciated.
thank you

Comment: It appears you have posted this same (similar) question before.  Please post your current code,  and specify what exactly within that code doesn't work for you.

Comment: yes the question is similar, but not the same,  the original had to compare only column A agains B, this one i need column A and B to be compared to Column C and D.  will update with current code.

Comment: Please post some sample data, as you did in your previous question, so we don't waste time with an incorrect interpretation of what you really want.

Comment: apologies for the limited infor.  have updated with examples.  have not stated any codes since i was way off track after seeing the first answer stated by Maciej Los

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

You need to iterate through the A & B column and compare to C & D.

```
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim str1 As String, str2 As String
Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

i = 2
Do While wsh.Range("A" & i) & wsh.Range("B" & i) <>""
    str1 = wsh.Range("A" & i) & wshRange("B" & i)
    j = i
    Do While wsh.Range("C" & j) & wsh.Range("D" & j) <>""
        str2 = wsh.Range("C" & j) & wsh.Range("D" & j)
        If str1 = str2 Then
            'your logic here
        End If
        j = j+1
    Loop
    i = i+1
Loop
```

Note: It's very slow. I decide to show it to provide basic comparison (each to each).

**Solution 2**

Solution 2 is bit complecated if you do not have basic knowledge about SQL and ADO. 
Using command like this:

```
SELECT A, B
FROM [Sheet1$] 
WHERE ((A NOT IN(SELECT C AS A FROM [Sheet1$])) AND (B NOT IN (SELECT D AS B FROM [Sheet1$])))
```

you're able to get records which does not match to each other.

Comment: just want to confirm something as i am still learning all of this.  1st solution - it states that it will check for comparison between the columns, but it wont actualy start checking because there is no lines to let it start checking.  am i correct in this?  thank you

Comment: @ Maciej Los.  my vba knowledge is not nearly good enough to figure this out.  tried to work with the 1 code you provided but not getting anything to work with it.  any help will be apreciated.

Comment: What you need to know? How can i help you?

Comment: not sure how to work with the code you provided,  ran it just like that and it did not do anything.  tried typing things in myself but that doesnt work either.  dont know enough to type codes myself.

Comment: It does nothing, because it's a skeleton. You need to improve this code by adding methods, functions, etc.